# How to add _ctypes to a Python 2.7 build at runtime?

Tags: python

I am working with an embedded custom Python 2.7 build, in which I can execute code in a very specific context. I need to monkey-patch a part of it, but all of it is considered built-in and can't be conventionally modified. I found a workaround ([forbiddenfruit](https://pypi.org/project/forbiddenfruit/0.1.0/) module), but it depends on ctypes, which, when attempted to import, raises `ImportError: No module named _ctypes`.

The _ctypes.lib doesn't seem to be included in the build, and it is closed-source, so I cannot recompile it and don't know any ways to modify it. Is there a way to somehow help this in runtime? I tried adding a path to _ctypes.lib from another python build to sys.path, but this didn't help. Also, the build operates on some virtual filesystem, so even putting files into internal directories is troublesome, if not impossible.

Also this is my first question on Stack Overflow, so I apologize for any style-related mistakes I may have made.

Comment: Assuming this is a unix-like embedded system, you want a dynamic list .so file not a .lib. Look for other .so files in your python distribution (could be under lib-dynload) and put it there. You may need to build python yourself to get the right version. For instance, mine is `_ctypes.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

Comment: It's actually windows, but I'll try to look for a dll. But where am I supposed to put the found file?

Comment: Are there other dlls in your distribution? Put it in that directory. Assuming you have sockets, you could try `import _socket;print(_socket.__file__)` (note the underscore to get the C implementation).

Comment: It imported successfully, but the second command raised `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'`. I'll try to look for it in the semi-decompiled code, though. EDIT: No, there is none there. And there are some dlls, but they aren't related to python in any way

Comment: Ouch! Look through the stuff in `sys.path`. Its going to depend on how your embedded system was packaged.

Comment: The sys.path looks like this: `[u'scripts/client', u'scripts/client_common', u'scripts/game_objects', u'scripts/common', u'scripts/common/Lib', u'scripts/common/site-packages', u'scripts/common/site-packages/backports.functools_lru_cache-1.4', u'scripts/common/site-packages/', u'scripts/common/site-packages/bitstring', u'scripts/common/site-packages/enum34-1.1.6', u'scripts/common/site-packages/typing-3.6.2']`. All of those are virtual directories

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213259/discussion-between-abel1502-and-tdelaney).